VDD and VSS pins shorted together
I have a PIC18F2420 MCU taken out of a PCB. There is a short between pins 8,19 and 20 which are VSS,VSS and VDD respectively.

Has this MCU completely failed?
One thing I have noticed when the MCU was still on the board, that sometimes it works but only during startup of the board.

So, how did you determine VDD and VSS are really shorted together, instead of just interpreting some test falsely to only think that they are shorted together with a false assumption? Did you use a multimeter? In ohms mode, or diode mode, or continuity beep mode?

Sure, Continuity beep mode.

I performed the measurements with the MCU was still on board and after I took it off. The short was caused by the MCU and not another component on the PCB.

@Bavly Did you buy this from a distributor with traceability? You could have a fake. Also did you unsolder it from the board? You could have damaged it if your iron was too hot.

@VoltageSpike There was a short circuit on the board, which disappeared after unsoldering the MCU.

You cannot use continuity beep mode to determine that VCC and GND are shorted.
Especially if the MCU is still soldered on board with other components such as capacitors and other ICs also connected between VCC and GND pins.
Unless other proof given, the MCU is not shorted.
At least use resistance measurement mode to determine a short. Anything above 10 ohms isn't a short, and 10 ohms does not really mean 10 ohms, as you are not measuring a resistor, but a semiconductor that may try to power up from the multimeter probes.
Most likely your multimeter has a beep threshold in the range of 60 to 600 ohms. And it does not mean a short circuit if it beeps. It simply means, the resistance measurement of something that wasn't a resistance at all is below the beeping threshold.
Also depending on which way the multimeter terminals were, it's possible you measured current flowing from GND to VCC terminal, which is explained by IO pin protection diodes. They will then clamp the voltage to about 1V to prevent damage, and your multimeter will beep as it simply sees probes shorted by two diodes in series.
If the MCU were short circuited like you claim, the voltage between VCC and GND would have been significantly less than the nominal voltage it was supposed to be, maybe near zero, and some supply regulator chip would heat up or would not start at all.

I totally agree with you. I also used resistance mode, measures around 4.5 ohms between VDD and VSS with the probes connected either way.

@Bavly Did you measure the resistance between both VSS pins, too?

@thebusybee yes I did, It was close to zero

@Bavly So you have a good impression how a short circuit looks like. Close to zero is really different from 4.5 Ohms.

@thebusybee much less than 4.5 as far as I can remember. But what is the significance of measuring the resistance between VSS pins?

@Bavly To learn the difference between an actual short circuit and the non-resistance impedance of a semiconductor part, when measuring resistance. You could experiment with BJT or diodes, and even if you have a low value in one direction, it has no short circuit.
